# Error al momento de Generar Pdf con DomPdf

Tags: php, dompdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Al momento de Generar un documento Pdf, cuando la tabla salta a otra pagina porque es muy larga, esta aparece atrás del header, el cual tiene el siguiente estilo:

```
header {
              position: fixed; left: 0; top: 10px; right: 0; height: 100px;  text-align: center;  
                 
            }
```

El codigo Completo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
 include '../model/conexion.php';
 include_once('../php/correo.php');
 require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';  
 use Dompdf\Dompdf;
 
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
 $conexion=conexion();
 $tema = 565;
$docente = utf8_decode(strtoupper($_SESSION['nombre_academico']));
  $tema2 = "";
       $autor = ""; 
        $celular = "";
         $correo = "";
         $sexo = "";
         $fecha_aprobacion = "";
 
 $sql = " SELECT
    t.id,
    t.tema,
    t.autor,
    t.fecha_aprobacion,
    e.nombres,
    e.apellidos,
    e.celular,
    e.correo_electronico,
    e.sexo
    
FROM
    tema t
    LEFT JOIN estudiantes e ON e.id = t.autor
  
WHERE t.tutor = (select tutor from tema where id = ".$tema.") and t.id = ".$tema.";";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die("Error en la consulta sql".mysqli_error($conexion));
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
       $tema2 = $row["tema"];
       $autor = $row["apellidos"]." ".$row["nombres"];
        $celular = $row["celular"];
         $correo = $row["correo_electronico"];
         $sexo =  $row["sexo"];
         $fecha_aprobacion =  $row["fecha_aprobacion"];
    }  
}

 $array = array("introduccion", "resumen", "planteamiento", "resumen","formulacion","objetivos","justificacion","antecedentes","bases","marco","hipotesis","diseño","tecnicas","observaciones");


 



 $valor = '<html> <head></head> <body> <style>


@page { margin:  50px; }
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{text-align:justify !important}

header {
              position: fixed; left: 0; top: 10px; right: 0; height: 100px;  text-align: center;  
                 
            }
             
            footer {
                    position: fixed;
                    bottom: 0cm;
                    left: 0cm;
                    right: 0cm;
                    height: 1cm;
                    
                    padding: 10px;
                     
                }
 </style>
 <header>
 

<p>
    <img class="image_resized" style="width:9.89%;" src="../img/unesum.png"  sizes="100vw" width="1456"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="image_resized" style="width:66.66%;" src="../img/cabeza.png" > &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<img class="image_resized" style="width:11.68%;" src="../img/logo.png"  sizes="100vw" width="296">
</p>
</header>
<main style="padding-top:150px; " >

<p style="text-align:right;">
    <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Jipijapa, 25 de agosto de 2021</span>
</p>
 
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Atención</span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Ing. Christian Ruperto Caicedo Plúa</span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"><strong>Coordinador de la carrera de Tecnologías de la Información</strong></span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Presente. -</span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
 
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Por medio de la presente nos dirigimos a usted muy respetuosamente, en virtud de la designación como miembros del tribunal de examinador del proyecto de titulación perteneciente al <strong>Sr. (ta). '.$autor.' &nbsp;</strong>Titulado: <strong>'.$tema2.'</strong>; para dar a conocer las observaciones sobre el trabajo mencionado las cuales a continuación se detallan:</span>
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
<figure class="table" style="width:566.27px; text-align-last: center;">
    <table style=" solid #000000; page-break-inside: auto;" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color:#d9d9d9; solid #000000;width:201.87px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"><strong>Instrumento de Evaluación</strong></span>
                    </p>
                </th>
                <th style="background-color:#d9d9d9; solid #000000;width:68.67px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"><strong>Cumple</strong></span>
                    </p>
                </th>
                <th style="background-color:#d9d9d9; solid #000000;width:68.67px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"><strong>No Cumple</strong></span>
                    </p>
                </th>
                <th style="background-color:#d9d9d9; solid #000000;width:227.07px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"><strong>Observaciones</strong></span>
                    </p>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ';
$valor4="";
$valor5="";
             foreach ($array as $valor1) {
    
    $valor3 = '<tr>
                <td style=" solid #000000;vertical-align:top;width:201.87px;">
                    <p style="text-align:justify;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">'.utf8_decode(strtoupper($valor1)).'</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                ';




      $sql2= "select ".$valor1." from revision_tribunal where id_tema = ".$tema."";
 $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2) or die("Error en la consulta sql".mysqli_error($conexion));
 
     if(mysqli_num_rows( $resultado2) > 0){
$contador = 0;
      $revision = "";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)){

         if($row2["0"]!=""){
               
          $contador++;
          $revision = $revision." ".$row2["0"]."<br>";
         }
     }
    
         if($contador>0){


             $valor4= $valor4.'<td style=" solid #000000;width:68.67px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style=" solid #000000;width:68.67px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        X
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style=" solid #000000;vertical-align:top;width:227.07px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"></span>
                          '.$revision.'
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>';
 

         }else{

            $valor4= $valor4.'<td style=" solid #000000;width:68.67px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        X
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style=" solid #000000;width:68.67px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style=" solid #000000;vertical-align:top;width:227.07px;">
                    <p style="text-align:justify;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;"></span>
                          
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>';
         }
$valor5 = $valor5.$valor3.$valor4;
}


$valor3="";
$valor4="";

}


            
     $valor2='   </tbody>
    </table>
</figure>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Particular que se informa para los fines pertinentes.</span>
</p>
<p style="margin-left:48px;text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
<p style="text-align:justify;">
    <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Atentamente,</span>
</p>
<p style="margin-left:48px;text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
<p style="margin-left:48px;text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
<p style="margin-left:48px;text-align:justify;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
<figure class="table" style="width:566.27px;">
    <table style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;vertical-align:top;width:283.13px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Ing. Hugo Andreé Vera Cedeño</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;vertical-align:top;width:283.13px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Ing. Hugo Andreé Vera Cedeño</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;vertical-align:top;width:283.13px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Miembro del Tribunal Examinador</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;vertical-align:top;width:283.13px;">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Miembro del Tribunal Examinador</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;vertical-align:top;width:566.27px;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        &nbsp;
                    </p>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Ing. Hugo Andreé Vera Cedeño</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-style:hidden;border-width:1px;vertical-align:top;width:566.27px;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="text-align:center;">
                        <span style="font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;">Miembro del Tribunal Examinador</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</figure>
<p style="text-align:center;">
    &nbsp;
</p>
 
</main> </body> </html>';
 $variablefinal = $valor.$valor5.$valor2;
$dompdf->loadHtml($variablefinal);
// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');
// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
//$dompdf->stream();

$output = $dompdf->output();

file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);

echo $valor.$valor5.$valor2;
?>
```

Quisiera saber como hago para que la generación de la tabla sea abajo del header y no atrás como se muestra en la siguiente imagen

Comment: y esto de que forma se arregla o esta relacionado a javascript?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estás dejando margen superior suficiente solo 50px, te recomiendo cambiarlo a 110px y lo demás le colocas 50px.

El cambio sería el siguiente, donde dice:

```
@page { margin:  50px; }
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Sustitúyelo por:

```
@page { margin:  110px 50px 50px 50px; } 
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```